# Jpa Optimistic locking without version attribute in database possible?

Tags: jpa, version, optimistic-locking, transient

We can not change the data model and we are not allowed to add a version field on certain tables.

Also pessimistic locking isn't an option. Because:

1. A row was read from the DB in one transaction and displayed in a web application.
2. Maybe a hour later the user changes the data and try to save.
3. Now we have a second transaction to save the changed data and an exception has to be thrown is if an other user or process changed the data meanwhile.

Be feet ist clear: We have to compare the original data with the actial data on the DB and save only if it's not changed.

But can jpa help to achieve that?

I tried to combine

```
@Version
@Transactional
int entityHash
```

And calculate the hash in

```
@PostLoad
```

But Hibernate internally stores the version before postload is called.

We can compare changed data manually but is there a way to use jpa functionality instead?

Comment: "But Hibernate internally stores the version before postload is called." - why is that a problem? JPA optimistic locking works in a way that it will use the value it read in when writing - so it needs that original value. Your issue might be that you are not supposed to be setting the version like you would for other writable columns - JPA does it for you when it detects changes were made to the entity. What you want will be outside of JPA and into JPA implementation native api, so that you can use your own versioning system, or other systems, like all fields being used to detect changes

Comment: See https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/4.0/jpa/extensions/jpa-extensions.html#optimisticlocking